# Concatenate two string with comma

Tags: string, matlab, concatenation, string-concatenation

I am newer in MATLAB.
I have a code like this

```
results=a(1,1)+','+a(1,2);
```

`a` is an array of words. I just want to concatenate the first two words in my array.

After running I get this error:

```
Undefined function or method 'plus' for input arguments of type 'cell'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error suggests that `a` is a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), which means you use curly brackets (`{}`) to access the data inside it. You can concatenate like this:

```
results = [a{1,1} a{1,2}];
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [`strjoin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strjoin.html):

```
strjoin(a(1,1:2).')
```

Generally, it takes a row cell array.  If you have a column, the transpose is necessary.  A basic example,

```
>> c = {'banana';'orange'}
>> strjoin(c(:)',',')
ans =    

banana,orange
```